# create 2 columns from 1 column of genotypic data in with NA in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create two columns of data from a single column such that if a column has the number "2", it will split into two columns as "2" and "2"; "1" will become "2" and "0", while "0" will be "0" and "0". I was successful with the following code (see below) when I don't have missing data, but I am finding a hard time figuring out how to tell R to leave "NA" as "NA" in the two new columns it creates for "NA". Attached are sample pictures of one i successfully did (rat) and one for which I need some help with (rat2).

```
rat <- read.csv("rat.csv",sep=",",quote="\"", dec=".", fill=FALSE, comment.char = "", header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)

m=dim(rat)[1]
n=dim(rat)[2]
newrat <- (matrix(0, ncol = 2*n, nrow = m));

for (i in 1: m) {
for (j in 1:n) {
if (rat[i,j]==2) {
newrat[i,(2*j-1):(2*j)]=c(2,2);
}
 else if (rat[i,j]==1) {
 newrat[i,(2*j-1):(2*j)]=c(2,0);
}
}
```

[image: rat data that worked]

[image: rat2 data I need help with]

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_ (see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Specifically, it would be helpful if you could post your data using `dput()`.

Comment: Why is column SNP5 in rat.csv split, that columns only contains 0's and 1's.  Thought the criteria for splitting was that the column contained a 2.  Is this correct.  I think taking some time to reword your question will really help potential answers.

Comment: @JacobH - I don't think that is right - there are 3 rules: (A) if a column has the number "2", it will split into two columns as "2" and "2"; (B) "1" will become "2" and "0", while (C) "0" will be "0" and "0". The example seems correct to me, albeit in a ridiculous screenshot format.

Comment: @thelatemail I might be missing something, but column SNP5 does not contain a "2" in the first screen shot.  However, it is still split, as seen in the second screenshot.  According to Nolage86's criteria, this should not occur, right?

Comment: @JacobH - Rule (B) in my comment says a `1` splits into `2 / 0`

Comment: @thelatemail, I see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you want.  Here is some ugly code.  Though it can be generalized to any size `data.frame`, I think.

```
d <- data.frame(t = c(NA, 2, NA), x = c(2,1,0), y = c(2,2,2), z = c(0,1,1))

d2 <- d[, sort(rep(names(d), 2))]

d3 <- t(d2)

d3[d3 == 1 & !is.na(d3)] <- rep(c(2,0), length(d3[d3 == 1 & !is.na(d3)])/2)

res <- t(d3)
```

There are likely cleaner ways to do this so you might want to play with the code.  This approach, however, will be dramatically faster than your original approach.  It does not use any loops!

Comment: Another good answer that did the job! Sorry about how I worded my question, and thanks for taking the time to send this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a go employing `lapply` on each column with a `match` to grab the appropriate values from a `keys` table which outlines your rules:

```
d <- data.frame(x = c(2,1,0), y = c(2,2,2), z = c(0,2,1), t = c(NA, 2, NA))
#  x y z  t
#1 2 2 0 NA
#2 1 2 2  2
#3 0 2 1 NA

keys <- data.frame(id=c(2,1,0),out1=c(2,2,0),out2=c(2,0,0))
#  id out1 out2
#1  2    2    2
#2  1    2    0
#3  0    0    0

do.call(cbind,lapply(d, function(x) keys[match(x,keys$id),][-1] ))
#  x.out1 x.out2 y.out1 y.out2 z.out1 z.out2 t.out1 t.out2
#1      2      2      2      2      0      0     NA     NA
#2      2      0      2      2      2      2      2      2
#3      0      0      2      2      2      0     NA     NA
```

Comment: bingo! it did the magic! Sorry about how I worded my question. I will pay more attention to that next time. I like the fact that your code does not include a loop. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Nolage86 - it does include a loop in reality - `lapply` is just a loop for the most part, but it is often cleaner and easier to understand.